# Javascript Promise - reject or resolve an empty result from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I was wondering what should be the good practice in that scenario :
A method return a promise when interogating a database, the database doesn"t found anything and return an empty result.

Should I resolve or reject the promise ?

Comment: it totally depends on what you need to do next but there are no rule for that

Comment: Well that depends on whether the existence of data constitutes fulfilment, or whether it's OK to have no data.